# How to put dots after section letters in Appendix

Tags: sectioning, appendices

I want to enumerate sections in Appendices by letters and I have succeeded. But how can I put dots after letters? I tried to use the command \renewcommand like first few lines, but it did not work in Appendices.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}
{\section*{Appendix}
\renewcommand\thesection{\alph{section}.}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Bla, bla, bla.

\begin{appendices}

\section{Proof of Proposition 1}

ABC

\end{appendices} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, you didn't succeed. What you're seeing is just the default behavior. You're not even using a subappendices environment, so that renewcommand isn't doing anything. Use `\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}` instead or put `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}.}` right after `\begin{appendices}`. Use uppercase `\Alph` not lowercase `\alph` unless you want lowercase letters.

Comment: What you have suggested works well. Thank you!